# Google Home integration Sample

Tags: node.js

I downloaded google home sample code from https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-smart-home-nodejs,then I followed the RAREDME.md step by step,But to this step which I posts as follow picture, I clicked on the submit button, It just jumped to a blank page, nothing at all. why?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dgPD.png)

Comment: The problem appears to be with the setting up ngrok.io connection

Comment: @BharathvajGanesan How to set up ngrok.io connection sir?thanks

Comment: Check the official docs to get started [ngrok.io](https://ngrok.com/docs). **Ngrok**, a very cool, lightweight tool that creates a secure tunnel on your local machine along with a public URL you can use for browsing your local site.

Comment: @BharathvajGanesan ok,thanks.